# cron.hourly sendmail errors even though my scripts do not involve sending mail

Tags: bash, cron, email, sendmail

I have only one very simple shell script in /etc/hourly.cron. It just controls a Twitter bot- it runs a short python script that posts to Twitter using tweepy. It does not involve email or any sendmail commands.

I had this set up for nearly a year with no problems, but now it is failing with odd errors related to sendmail.

First, in /var/log/syslog, I was getting this:

```
Dec 30 10:17:01 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 CRON[29527]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 30 10:17:02 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 cron[865]: Please install an MTA on this system if you want to use sendmail!
Dec 30 10:17:02 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 CRON[29526]: (root) MAIL (mailed 2136 bytes of output but got status 0x00ff from MTA#012)
```

I then installed postfix to try to debug this and got this:

```
Dec 30 15:17:01 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 CRON[4542]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 30 15:17:03 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 cron[865]: sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Dec 30 15:17:03 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 postfix/sendmail[4546]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory
Dec 30 15:17:03 sarah-ThinkPad-X220 CRON[4541]: (root) MAIL (mailed 250 bytes of output but got status 0x004b from MTA#012)
```

I am a cron novice and have no idea why an MTA would be needed at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your script probably contains some output that cron is trying to mail to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, any output produced by things run by cron is sent by e-mail to the owner of the crontab. To disable this, either make sure your scripts do not produce any output, or redirect it to `/dev/null` in your crontab, or add `MAILTO=""` at the top of your crontab.

Comment: Thanks-- I added the MAILTO="". I'll see if it works in a few minutes, when my cron.hourly is scheduled to run :)

Answer (score 1):

Just set in top of the cron file

```
MAILTO=""
```

And no mail will be send